# How to convert few names into actual strings with quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to convert string like data which donot have quotes ' ' or " " around them into a list.

I tried to create a list and iter thru it to add quotes.

I wonder if there is pythonic way or an already in-built function to do this.

```py
col_list = [col1, col2, col3, col4]

cnvrted_list = []

for col in col_list:
    item = "'" + col + "'"
    cnvrted_list.append(item)

print (new_list)

NameError: name 'col1' is not defined.
```

```
Expected Output should have quotes '' to these values

new_list = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
```

Comment: you could do a list comp like so: `converted_list = [f"'{word}'" for word in col_list]`

Comment: Aren't `col1`, `col2`', ... variables? Can you provide `print(col_list)`?

Comment: You did not make clear what the input data is and where it comes from.

Comment: is `col_list` a string, i.e. `"[col1, col2, col3, col4]"`?

Comment: I can make it a string, but I would have to put those " " quotes manually.

col_list = [col1, col2, col3, col4.........col_n] nothing more nothing less

Answer (score 0):

you could do a list comp like so: `converted_list = [f"'{word}'" for word in col_list]`

```
>>> a = ["hi", "lol", "back"]
>>> b = [f"'{word}'" for word in a]
>>> b
["'hi'", "'lol'", "'back'"]
```

Looks like the elements in your col_list are variables but haven't been defined prior to being called in the line where you initialize col_list. Wrap them in quotes to treat them as strings

Comment: my col_list is not variables, they are string's but they do-not have quotes (which is making python treat them as variables).   I want to put these quotes programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

add "" around col1, col2, col3, col4

```
col_list = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]

cnvrted_list = []

for col in col_list:
    item = "'" + col + "'"
    cnvrted_list.append(item)

print (cnvrted_list)
```

result is ["'col1'", "'col2'", "'col3'", "'col4'"]

Comment: The whole issue is I cannot add Quotes, the col_list I have is very huge